# How to use the Project Path from the Project Explorer to develop my own plugin?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

Heyho,

I'm trying to develop my own Eclipse Plugin.
It should be visiable as a new entry in the PopupMenu from the Eclipse Project Explorer. I would like to right-click at the Project and execute a little bit of JavaCode and need  the project path from the marked project.
So how do i get the specific project path?

Comment: To show the menu if and only if one project is selected, you have to define this in the `plugin.xml`. How to get the _IProject_ in the handler see for example: http://git.eclipse.org/c/pde/eclipse.pde.ui.git/tree/ui/org.eclipse.pde.ui/src/org/eclipse/pde/internal/ui/editor/OpenManifestHandler.java#n44

Comment: What are you asking about? How to add the pop-up menu? How to restrict its visibility? How to write the command handler? Asking for all of that is too broad, show what you have done so far.

Comment: I have many Projects, which contains XML-Files. A part of my work is, to merge these files form the Project Repo.
The actuall Solution is, to choose manually the Path, from which project the xml's should be merged.
My idea: Add an new entry to the context menu in the project explorer view, where my plugin get the project path and execute the merge.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EgwK9mU0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How to add the popup menu see: ***[Adding menus, toolbar and popup menus to the Eclipse IDE - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html)***
2. The **project location** can be computed **via current selection**: see e. g. source code of [OpenManifestHandler, line 52..86](http://git.eclipse.org/c/pde/eclipse.pde.ui.git/tree/ui/org.eclipse.pde.ui/src/org/eclipse/pde/internal/ui/editor/OpenManifestHandler.java?id=2d1ced4a6a15b97db9dce45048fe3740fe6870c6#n52) for details.
3. *IProject -> File*: `getRawLocation().makeAbsolute().toFile();`